# Codeigniter in localhost WAMP Windows

Tags: windows, codeigniter, localhost, wamp

I try to use Codeigniter in localhost with WAMP.
Problem is, that I can open just basic function in basic controller, and when I tried to use root like site/controller/function, its do not work. Result is that it put me back to wamp start page, or text that page not found.

Mostly I found solutions about makingthe .htaccess file, and many variations what to put in it.
To uncomment rewrtie mod in wamp .conf file. And in my web page to leave index_page empty.

But It do not work for me.

My controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {

            $this->load->view('index');
            }

    function slide() {

            $this->load->view('slider');
            }
 }
```

And my web page is in: www/mysite/....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|indexcp\.php?|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/.-]+)$ index.php?$1 

RewriteRule ^(CSI) index.php?/CSI
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

**EDIT**

Add the above code here

[image]

Don't change any thing in `CI system`..

Once check this [repo](https://github.com/mrsrinivas/ci_template)

Comment: @daniela.svas: set `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';` in config

Comment: make sure it's in the same folder as your index.php

Comment: I changed it. same folder with index, or the base folder of all codeigniter stuff? or i n applicaton/view file?